# ContraintLayout: Optional top view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to make the following design using ConstraintLayout. The screen should be devided into a top section (50% of screen), and a bottom section (50% of screen). The top section should be able to hide according to some application logic, making the bottom section use the remaining blank space on top.

My layout is as follows:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />
```

Comparison image showing on the left side how the layout looks with both sections visible. On the right side the top section is gone but the bottom RecyclerView does not stretch to use the top space. I added padding to the ImageView and RecyclerView to better illustrate the relationship between the views.

[image: Comparison image showing on the left side how the layout looks with both sections visible. On the right side the top section is gone but the bottom RecyclerView does not stretch to use the top space]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set equal vertical weights for both `view`s in the chain so each occupies 50% of the space. If you set the top `view`'s visibility to `GONE` in code or in XML, the bottom `view` will fill the remaining space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. That indeed solves my issue and is seems simpler. Although I still think the solution I posted should be a valid working solution, but it doesn't work due to some bizarre issue.

Comment: Your code is working as intended. The guideline is just a helper object and has a fixed position. There is no reason why the bottom view would expand upwards beyond this guideline even if the top one is gone.

Comment: The bottom view is bounded on top by the ImageView, not the guideline. Since the ImageView is `gone` and shown on the top left corner, the RecyclerView should expand to maintain its top side constrained to the bottom side of the ImageView.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, I missed it. Though even with the ImageView being `gone` the constraints are still respected and actual dimensions will not be changed (on the right it's still constrained by the guideline).